# Autowired Service not injected when called from Token Filter

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've created a Filter to validate tokens sent by my teamates requests, to do that I get a token key located in my properties through a service I created, but I keep getting a NullPointerException beacause my propertyService isn't getting injected...what am I doing wrong ?

This is my service

```
@Profile("default")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Configuration
public class PropertyService {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(PropertyService.class);

    public String getProperty(String property) {
        try {
            String prop = env.getRequiredProperty(property);
            return prop;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("some message");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new PropertyDoesNotExist();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Filter

```
@Service
public class TokenService extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    PropertyService propertyService;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean tokenFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filter = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filter.setFilter(new TokenService());
        filter.addUrlPatterns("/token/*");
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String tokenKey = propertyService.getProperty("token-key");

        //Do something with the key...

        if (NullValueService.isNull(token)) {
            new CustomExceptionResponse().buildAndWriteCustomExceptionForHandlers(response, CustomExceptionMessage.TOKEN_NOT_FOUND);
        } else if (!validateToken(token)) {
            new CustomExceptionResponse().buildAndWriteCustomExceptionForHandlers(response, CustomExceptionMessage.TOKEN_INVALID);
        } else if (!validateTokenExpiration(token)) {
            new CustomExceptionResponse().buildAndWriteCustomExceptionForHandlers(response, CustomExceptionMessage.TOKEN_EXPIRED);
        }else{
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you instatntiating your TokenService? Where is this getting used?

Comment: Is the `PropertyService` under the same packaging of your SpringbootApplication ? Can you add the stacktrace or/and add your project structure ?

Comment: @pvpkiran I edited my question with my Filter Instantiation, that happens to be in the same class

Comment: @GabLeg yes, both services are on diferent packages but under my SpringbootApplication

Answer (score 2):

Move your FilterRegistrationBean code to a separate file like this

```
@Configuration
class Someclass

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean tokenFilter(TokenService tokenService) { // TokenService will be Autowired by spring. This will have propertyService Autowired in turn.
        FilterRegistrationBean filter = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filter.setFilter(tokenService);
        filter.addUrlPatterns("/token/*");
        return filter;
    }
}
```

You should not use `new`. If you do so, then you lose out on Spring autowiring capabilities, which is exactly what is happening in your case. And hence NPE

Comment: yeah ! that made the trick ! thanks ! appreciated the tip about using new too !